# How to use Next.js Dynamic Import for multiple exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For dynamic import Next.js recommends this:

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))
```

But I have my code like this to import all exports:

```
import * as SectionComponents from "../components/sections";
```

And the contents of above file:

```
export { default as Team } from "./team";
export { default as Gallery } from "./gallery";
export { default as Logos } from "./logos";
// could be n number
```

Now how do I import that using dynamic()?

Comment: try to destructure {*} in {import *} with const {Team, Gallery, Logos} = dynamic(... )

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do this directly. You'll have to import each named export separately. See this discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13139

Comment: @FrédéricLang It throws `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Comment: @brc-dd That thread doesn't provide an answer :(

Comment: @SurjithSM That's because the problem hasn't any proper (direct) solution yet. You need to do this in a similar way as the question, i.e. dynamically import each named export separately.

Comment: @brc-dd Thanks, I'm trying to save some size on [slug] where some sections appear on some pages, where others do not. Do you think I can keep using the current method? because even for other pages [slug] is being called. Bit confused there.

Comment: @SurjithSM Well I am not sure if this will work properly because barrel files don't properly work with Next.js. You can try using it and see if code splitting works. If it does, then you don't need to worry. The chunk corresponding to the component will only be requested when it is rendered. Unused components won't consume bandwidth. If this doesn't work, then you should try dynamically importing the components directly from `/components/sections/team`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
const Team = dynamic(() => import('../components/sections').then((c) => c.Team ), {
  loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>,
})
```